# get memory usage on cuda context

Tags: cuda, cuda-context

Is there a way that I can get cuda context memory usage rather than having to use cudaMemGetInfo which only reports global information of a device? or at least a way to get how much memory is occupied by the current application?

Comment: In short: [no](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044191/determine-memory-cuda-context-memory-usage/?offset=5)

Comment: nvidia-smi provides this information (per-process memory usage) for Tesla and Quadro GPUs.  Which means it should be possible to retrieve it using NVML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be impossible [[No]](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/determine-memory-cuda-context-memory-usage/67460/2). However, retrieving per-process memory usage is still a good alternative. And as Robert has pointed out, per-process memory usage can be retrieved using [NVML](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlDeviceQueries.html#group__nvmlDeviceQueries), specifically, by using `nvmlDeviceGetComputeRunningProcesses` function.